# Can you pass a typeof a class to a constructor and have it match the generic type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have models that conform to a base class and I want to be able to have corresponding services, with a base service that can define helper methods.

```
type UnknownJson = Record<string, unknown>;

class BaseModel {
  constructor(json: UnknownJson) {
    ...
  }

  static toJson<T>(record: Partial<T>): UnknownJson {
    ...
  }
}

class Car extends BaseModel {}

class BaseService<M extends BaseModel> {
  constructor(private ModelClass: ...) { ... }

  fromJson(json: UnknownJson): M {
    return new this.ModelClass(json);
  }
}

class CarService extends BaseService<Car> {
  constructor() {
    super(Car);
  }
}
```

If I set the type in the base service constructor as `() => M`, then I cannot leverage the static methods available on `BaseModel`. If I write the type as `typeof BaseModel & ((json: UnknownJson) => M`, then the return type of the constructor is not properly overridden and it believes it will return `BaseModel`, not `M`.

Comment: Does [Abstract construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-construct-signatures) work for you? `constructor(private ModelClass: new (json: UnknownJson) => M) { ... }` See https://tsplay.dev/N95eMN

Comment: @Lesiak the problem with that implementation is that the `ModelClass` does not have the static properties of the class (e.g. `toJson`).

Comment: How about `constructor(private ModelClass: (new (json: UnknownJson)  => M) & {toJson: <T>(record: Partial<T>) => UnknownJson}) {  }` https://tsplay.dev/Wyjv6w

Comment: @Lesiak for some reason, that doesn't respect the response type from the constructor anymore. It's really strange. However, I did use `& typeof BaseModel` instead, which allows access to all class methods on BaseModel.